# Relation latest of many without ID

Tags: php, laravel

Sensors table

```
id  name        
1   Sensor no1
2   Sensor no2
3   Sensor no3
```

Temperatures table (log table)

```
temperature  sensor_id   timestamp
2.85         1           2021-10-19 18:37:34
5.05         2           2021-10-19 18:37:34
2.90         3           2021-10-20 18:37:34
5.65         1           2021-10-21 18:37:34
21.5         3           2021-10-22 18:37:34
```

In eloquent I have sensor model with relation

```
public function latestTemperature()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Temperature::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

I get SQL error that **temperatures.id** does not exist. - I do not have ID in that table.
How can I tell it to where sensor id = x order by timestamp desc limit 1 or something?

```
Unknown column 'temperatures.id' 'field list'-s (SQL: select `temperatures`.* from `temperatures` inner join (select MAX(`temperatures`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, `temperatures`.`sensor_id` from `temperatures` where `temperatures`.`sensor_id` in (1) group by `temperatures`.`sensor_id`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `temperatures`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`sensor_id` = `temperatures`.`sensor_id`)
```

**EDIT 1**

If only I could replace the id column in that query with timestamp....

```
select `temperatures`.* 
from `temperatures` 
inner join (select MAX(`temperatures`.`timestamp`) as `id_aggregate`, `temperatures`.`sensor_id` from `temperatures` where `temperatures`.`sensor_id` in (295)
    group by `temperatures`.`sensor_id`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `temperatures`.`timestamp` and `latestOfMany`.`sensor_id` = `temperatures`.`sensor_id`
```

**EDIT 2**

I defined a custom newhasmany relation?

```
public function latestTemperature()
{
    return $this->newHasMany(
        Temperature::select()->join(
            DB::raw(
                '(select MAX(`temperatures`.`timestamp`) as `id_aggregate`, `temperatures`.`sensor_id` as id from `temperatures`
            group by `temperatures`.`sensor_id`) as agg'
            ),
            function ($join) {
                $join->on('agg.id_aggregate', '=', 'temperatures.timestamp');
                $join->on('agg.id', '=', 'temperatures.sensor_id');
            }

        ),
        $this,
        'sensor_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

It works, but is this the correct way to solve this?
Problem with this is that the aggregating subquery does not include the 'where id in (...)', how can I add that?

Answer (score 0):

you may use **hasMany** instead:

```
return $this->hasMany(Temperature::class, 'sensor_id', 'id');
```

Comment: This returns all data from temperatures table, but I need only the latest.

Comment: @flowstacker Order by desc and limit 1?

Comment: @JelmerdeVries If I try to get multiple sensors, the relation query will become this:
select * from `temperatures` where `temperatures`.`sensor_id` in (1,2,3) order by `timestamp` desc limit 1 - so doesn't work.